# How to make my code become beautiful, I have to use callbak to get db, but I don't want to use this way

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, orm, js-beautify

I make a class name Chocolate, and put some mongodb function in it, so I need create a connection, and get db from callback, and this way make my code become ugly

Code:

```
let chocolate = new Chocolate(url,
  db => {
    chocolate.insert("en", { "h": 1 }).disconnect();
  })
```

The class code is here:

```
class Chocolate {
  constructor(url, callback) {
    this.url = url;
    this.connect()
      .then(db => {
        this.db = db;
        callback(db);
      });
  }

  connect(callback) {
    return MongoClient
      .connect(this.url);
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.db.close();
  }

  insert(className, dataObject) {
    const collection = this.db.collection(className);
    collection.insert(dataObject)
      .then(
      result => {
        return result.insertedIds;
      });
    return this;
  }

}
```

I konw that orm can help me, but I don't want to use some orm. because I only need a little function.

So, how to make these code become beautiful?

Or like this:

```
let chocolate - new Chocolate(url);
chocolate.insert(xxxx).find(xxxx).run().disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try converting those callbacks into promises

https://benmccormick.org/2015/12/30/es6-patterns-converting-callbacks-to-promises/

Comment: www, let me see

Comment: converting,enn, How to make class use promise QAQ

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do async code inside a constructor, instead call your connect function after you instantiate your object.

Generally, it is considered bad practice to return anything from a constructor that isn't an instance of your object.

Comment: ok, and I try it: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8aosx9t3/). But I can't make this._db = db. I want to cry QAQ

Comment: WoW, this is so amazing. `const self = this;` this code let me memory some old quesiton :)

Comment: Well I just hope it helped!

Comment: wuuu, this is a sad story, when I use `console.log(self._db)` ; it will undefined like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8aosx9t3/2/)

Comment: well, some people say : `MongoClient.connect(this.url).then(here is await);` and this will make this._db become undefined

Comment: Uncertain what you mean but you should change your insert and connect to use promises, kinda like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8aosx9t3/3/)